# Artifactory unable to download Eclipse plugin's/artifacts. java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.core.runtime.OperationCanceledException

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, xtext

I am facing two issues as explained below.

1. java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.core.runtime.OperationCanceledException"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
2. Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.eclipse.xtend:xtend-maven-plugin:2.12.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.6.0, org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.core.runtime:jar:3.6.0: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.6.0

I understand that the resolution mentioned in the bug report [0] should ideally fix the issue. In order for that to happen, I need the bundles in #2, that apparently are not getting downloaded.

From the error log in #2, it's clear that the required dependencies cannot be found in the artifactory. What I do not understand is why these plugins are not getting provisioned? Provided below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFhWg.png) is the list of P2 repositories that I have configured in the artifactory. I have confirmed that the required plugins are available for download in the below P2 repositories.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFhWg.png)

[0] https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/issues/1231#issuecomment-40112556

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFhWg.png) http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201706281000/, http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen, http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6/R-3.6-201006080911, http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops2/R20170516192513/repository

Artifactory version: 6.0.3, Eclipse Xtext version: 2.12.0, Eclipse version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0), Build id: 20170620-1800

Any help/pointers are highly appreciated.

Tx in advance.

Comment: It's possible that the 3.6 versions, as you might tell from the URLs, being 8 years old, have been archived and are no longer at that location. Can you use the Oxygen (or better yet the current Photon) versions?

Comment: If you look at the bug report [0], it says that you can "pin the jdt version of your xtext release". The Xtext release I am using is 2.12.0 and it internally depends on jdt.core (3.6.0).

I confirmed the 3.6 repo and it seems to be available.

Oxygen is already configured along with 3.6. Please see [1] above.

Comment: you are talking about maven and p2 artifacts. in the case of the error above p2 deps should not be involved at all. so where do you infer from that you need jdt 3.6. there are old jdt plugin versions that are not avail, in maven central. xtext 2.12 was built against jdt 3.12 https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/blob/v2.12.0/gradle/versions.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following should work for 2.12

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>a</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtend.lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
                <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/xtend-gen/main</outputDirectory>
                            <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/xtend-gen/test</testOutputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.12.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.100</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Regarding jdt3.6, I was wrong. I was able to fix the issue by adding the following

`<dependency>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
 <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
 <version>3.13.0</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
 <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.common</artifactId>
 <version>3.9.0</version>                       
</dependency>`